# How to open a pdf file in ms word through python

Tags: python, pdf, ms-word

I can easily left click on a word file and then say open with word. Ms word automatically converts the pdf sufficiently to a docx, without the formatting(I don't need the formatting). I want to automatically open a batch of pdf files and save them to another folder as docx type (preferably through python). Any suggestions on how to do this?

I have tried python libraries like pypdf2, but they do not get all the content of the document.
I am currently having to manually open the pdf file in ms word, then save it, and open and process it using python.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution would be use of os.system like this:

```
import os
os.system("'Path_to_your_word_exe' 'path_to_your_p df'")
```

There is a problem with spaces within a path with this solution, so I recommend using sub-process call:

```
import subprocesss
subprocess.call([r'raw path to word', r'raw path to file'])
```

example:

```
subprocess.call([r'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.exe', r'C:\Users\gopco\Downloads\SCYR.pdf'])
```

To automate your job for multiple files in a single directory use following code:

````
import win32com.client
import os

#start word
word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
#allow word to print error messages (if any)
word.visible = 1

pdfs_path = "./" # folder with pdfs
reqs_path = "./" # folder for saving docx files

for i, doc in enumerate(glob.iglob(pdfs_path+"*.pdf")):
    filename = doc.split('\\')[-1] #get just the file name
    in_file = os.path.abspath(doc) #absolute path
    print(in_file)
    wb = word.Documents.Open(in_file) #open the pdf in word
    out_file = os.path.abspath(reqs_path +filename[0:-4]+ ".docx".format(i)) #set the filename for saving the docx
    print("outfile\n",out_file)
    wb.SaveAs2(out_file, FileFormat=16) # file format for docx
    print("success...")
    wb.Close()

word.Quit()```
````

Comment: This works nicely! Additionally, now that I have opened the pdf as a word, how can my python program access it? Is it possible to reference it somehow?  Or can I save it somehow? And then open it using doc2txt library

Comment: You can do whatever you need in word, save it and after that open the saved file via python. You cant access file opened in word from python. In case your problem is resolved now please accept the question.

Comment: Are you sure?  Can I not reference it while I am opening it? I just need to save the doc. Then I can easily open it in python. I have to do this for multiple files together. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TejasParanjape I have looked here and there and found a solution for you, the answer has been edited